# Can't update from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, system

My ubuntu 16.04 keeps popping up a screen saying "new version available, do you want to update to 18.04?" but after I click yes nothing happens. Is there any other way to update to 18.04?

Comment: Don't do it. In many cases  you won't be able to boot after this upgrade. At least you need to have a full backup.

Comment: @Pilot6 I agree with doing research to make sure that the hardware/space requirements comply before performing an upgrade, but the OP is asking for additional ways to upgrade.

Comment: Hardware/space is not enough. Some luck is also needed. I have lots of space, etc, but can't upgrade. There is too much difference between 16.04 and 18.04.

Comment: Open a terminal and try the command `do-release-upgrade`. The upgrade seems likely to fail gracefully, but it will emit a lot of helpful clues while it fails. Please edit your question to include the *complete* output, properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) to verify your system build meets the Ubuntu 18.04 Installation/System Requirements.

To upgrade using the command line instead of the graphical update manager:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install update-manager-core
do-release-upgrade
```

After completion, to verify the installation is successful, do:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Taken from [2 Ways to Upgrade From Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 To Ubuntu 18.04 (Graphical & Terminal)](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-to-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: Thank you, short, simple, precise, and easy to follow.